# UTC and Dates without time

Tags: c#, .net, utc

I have users in different time zones so I am storing dates in UTC format.

Since the dates are a schedule of payments I don't want a time.  The way I solve this is:

var utcDate = DateTime.Parse(newPaymentPlanRequest.StartDate.ToShortDateString());

This stores the date in the database as 2021-02-10 00:00:00.0000000.

That all seems fine.  However when I use TimeZoneInfo to convert the date go local, it sets the time to the previous day of the day I am looking for.

I am at a loss on how to handle this.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Marty

Comment: `However when I use TimeZoneInfo to convert the date go local,` Have you considered not doing that?

Comment: The problem when I setup a payment plan at 3:00 PST it will set the date as the next day, and then it will actually work as intended.

Comment: If you don't want the "time" portion of the `DateTime` then why do you care about time zones?

Comment: My advice is always to use [NodaTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime/) to deal with time zones and translation between them. Don't ever arbitrarily add or subtract any amount of time. If you need to know what a date and time UTC timestamp is in a given timezone, NodaTime will prevent bad calculations by effective use of a domain model that only allows semantically correct operations.

Comment: `The problem when I setup a payment plan at 3:00 PST it will set the date as the next day, and then it will actually work as intended.` OK, now I am confused. Is it working, or not working?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Include at least seven inputs and list the expected output for each of the seven inputs.

Comment: @Xerillo if I don't use time zones.  Then what date should I use when say starting a payment plan.  Just use the date of their time zone?

The other problem I have by doing that is then what time do I run the job to process the payment plan.

Comment: FYI, you can do `var utcDate = newPaymentPlanRequest.StartDate.Date;` instead of converting it to a string and then parsing it back to a `DateTime` object.

Comment: @RufusL that is so it strips the time so it stores in the database without a time stamp.

Comment: A `DateTime` always has a `Time` component. That's what the `00:00:00.0000000` part is. I was just giving you a way to shorten that code (the `Date` property returns the date with a zeroed-out time part).

Comment: `The other problem I have by doing that is then what time do I run the job to process the payment plan.` The job should run as a schedule (e.g. every hour) and see what payments need to be charged at that time.

Comment: I don't understand all the parsing.  To get a `DateTime` at midnight from a `DateTime` you use the [Date Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 2):

Since you storing all dates in UTC, why not also convert your billing process run date to UTC? Then comparison is apples to apples.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and just used the dates of their local time zone, and will run a job to process the transactions every hour.

Thank you for the help.